# HibernateItemWriter with only save

Tags: spring-batch

I tried to configure and use HibernateItemWriter. It is working as expected.
However, as per our process, we delete all the previous data before loading the new data. So, saveOrUpdate is not required here.

I wrote my own writer just to 'save' the data using Hibernate.

```
public void write(List<? extends T> modelObjectList) throws Exception{
        ...
        for(T t : modelObjectList){
            session.save(t);
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering, can we perhaps configure HibernateItemWriter to do only save?

Comment: The method to override should be - as per documentation - http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/HibernateItemWriter.html#doWrite-org.hibernate.SessionFactory-java.util.List-